# In what order should Ghost in the shell franchise be viewed

Tags: suggested-order, ghost-in-the-shell

I already watched the 1995 movie before thinking about deciding on an order since that movie started it all (in the anime part, of course the manga came first) but in which order should I continue viewing them?

Comment: I do not agree this is a duplicate as the other question looks for the starting place not the whole order